# Know the setting used in creating key pair in GNUPG4Win version 3.15

Tags: cryptography, key-management, gnupg

I am using GNUpg4Win version 3.15. For the last few hours I am trying to figure out what default settings are used for Cipher and Hash during key generation.

Basically I want to use AES-128, 3DES cipher for encryption and SHA-256 as Cryptographic Hash function.

I could see Sha256 as the default checksum program in Kleopatra.

gpa.conf file shows the following :

advanced-ui
show-advanced-options
detailed-view

Is there something I need to add here?

Can some one please help me out or point me in the right direction.

Comment: GPG (PGP) key is encrypted with one cipher (AES[128] or 3DES not both) and one s2k algorithm normally using a (crypto)hash, salt and iteration count. GnuPG2 uses a new format for privatekey files (in a subdirectory named `private-keys-v1.d`) with the traditionally-binary metadata in ASCII, and looking at these files with any hex editor it is easy to see what 'protection' was used. My 3.1.2 used `openpgp-s2k3-sha1-aes-cbc` with sha1, 8B salt, and claimed n=2242560 -- which is not compatible, but export to traditional format has n=2359296 (9<<(12+6)) instead. I see no option to change these.

Comment: Dave, thanks for looking into it. I am new to this and I am assuming I am using GPG. Coming back to the question, how do I know whether I am using AES128(need to use this) or 3DES ? Is it something I need to configure in gpa.conf file ?

Comment: Yes you are using GPG -- that's that an alternate abbreviation for GnuPG. More usefully you are almost certainly using GnuPG version 2, since that's what GnuPG4Win is based on, for as long as I've looked at it (which isn't all that long). Given v2, for an existing file, just look at the file as I said. AFAICS the cipher isn't configurable on 3.1.2, and I don't know if it is on 3.15 or if so how, which is why I didn't post an answer.